# How to draw some thing at the bing maps at the front end?

Tags: bing-maps

I was doing a project using bing maps and need to draw something on it. When I draw lines and polygon continuously, the map reacted really slow. I'm not sure whether the map will interact with the back-end every time I draws something on it. If that is true, is it possible to drawing thing at the front-end first and when users pushes SAVE, the program will save all the changes to the back-end at one time? How?

Comment: I don't understand the question... What do you mean by front-end, is it the "Client-side"? Everything in Bing Maps is drawn in client-side (javascript). Can you explain your problem a little bit better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using the JavaScript API. If this is the case all rendering occurs on the client side and not on the server. If you need a jump start on adding drawing tools to your map take a look at this module for Bing Maps: http://bingmapsv7modules.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Shape%20Toolbox%20Module